# CPU goes 100% due to so many http call in node js code. How I will optimize that code?

Tags: node.js, http

I am putting some sample code here from my application. 
I am calling update data function. In one minute I have 150 calls of http.
So due to this code my cpu goes 100% and I want to optimize this code.
Wanted to fix performance issue of this node js code.

```
function doSynchronousLoop(data) {

if (data.length > 0) {

    var loop = function(data, i) {

            if (++i < data.length) {

                var req = httpcall.request('http://myserverip/path', function(res) {
                            res.setEncoding('utf8');
                             res.on('data', function (chunk) {

                                setTimeout(function(){
                                        loop(data, i);
                                    }, 50);

                             });

                        });

                        req.on('error', function(err) {
                            console.error('error: ' ,err.stack.split("\n"));
                        });

                        req.write("");

                        req.end();
            }else{
                allData= [];

            }

    };
    loop(data, 0);
}else{
    allData= [];
}

function updateData(allData){
    doSynchronousLoop(allData);
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the purpose of your code.  It seems like you're making your `httpcall.request()` recursively for every item in `allData`.  Why not do it iteratively? Why are you nesting it in a Timeout with every `data` event?

Comment: About every 50ms, you start a new http request, long before the prior request has finished.  What do you expect or want to happen?  Your question asks how to optimize the code, but does not explain the desired behavior.  We cannot really help without knowing how the code is supposed to behave.  Do you want the requests to run serially, in parallel with at most 5 in flight at the same time?  Or something else?

Comment: I want to run one http call at a time. In one minute I have 150 calls of http. I clearly mention. My issue is cpu goes 100%. I want to solve that thing. @jfriend00

Comment: Your question does not say that you desire to run one http call at a time.  Please edit it to say that.

Comment: I want to do it synchronously that's why I put that. My http server hang up due to more http calls so I put timeout. @GibryonBhojraj

Comment: Synchronously?  HTTP calls in node.js are asynchronous, not synchronous.  If you want the next one to run after the prior one finishes, then you have to explicitly code it to do that.  Just don't call `loop()` again until the prior http call is completely done.

Comment: So I put callback function. once my http request response came it goes into that function and then there is timeout of 50 ms and again next url call will execute.

Comment: Actually, that's not really synchronously.  Your callback calls a new HTTP request on every "data" event.  Unless the get request is really short, it'll fire multiple times, so several more http.get calls will be fired BEFORE the first one fires its `end` request.

Comment: Ok thanks. That will help me to solve my issue. @GibryonBhojraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback calls a new HTTP request on every "data" event. Unless the get request is really short, it'll fire multiple times, so several more http.get calls will be fired BEFORE the first one fires its end request.  So, if you change your callback to fire on the `end` event instead of the `data` event, it will behave synchronously.